# ajax returns HTML source code instead of String

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i have a web project , all i wanna do is to send a String to the servlet then return the same string to the jsp Page(formList.jsp) and display it:

javascript code to send the String :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var value = $('#val').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            data:{value:value},
            url:'FormList',
            success:function(result){
                $('#res').text(result);
            }
        });
    });
    
});
```

'FormList' Servlet doPost :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        String value = request.getParameter("value");
        response.getWriter().print(value);
```

}

web.xml (located in WEB-INF):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee                       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<servlet>
<servlet-name>FormList</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>FormList</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>FormList</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/FormList</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

but the when i click the submit button, the result i get is the formList.jsp page HTML source : (`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ....`)

*i'm overriding the service method in servlet to initialize the formList.jsp

i think that doPost is not executed at all
any help please

Comment: Are you definitely hitting your `doPost` method (is the path in the `url` property of your ajax request right?)  Or are you getting back a 404/error page from the server?

Comment: run server in debug mode and check if dopost is getting executed and see what is inside String value. if you not equipped with debugger just system.out.println value to check.

Comment: @83N , yes it's right (FormList) , should i put make it (/FormList) ?

Comment: @ShubhamKadlag i tried , doPost is not getting executed :/ , what could be the reason ?

Comment: @TamerNassar - yes I'd check that path is correct/relative to the page that's requesting it  - your doPost should just return plain text of the submitted value - the `<!DOCTYPE html...` suggests the server is returning a different/error page...?

Comment: @83N , i forgot to mention , when i put some random url(jashdka) and submit the button i don't get any error , when i put this url (/FormList) i get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FormList .

Comment: @83N no , it returns the same page HTML source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend checking out BalusC's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax) on a question about how to do ajax with servlets.

I noticed you are using jquery, you can also create your ajax request like this:

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#submit", function() { 
    var value = $('#val').val(); //get value you want to send
    var params = {value : value}; //set it as one of the parameters

    $.post("FormList", $.param(params), function(response) { //make ajax request
                 $('#res').text(response); //retrieve response and set it to #res
    });
        });
</script>
```

But anyway, the reason why you are only seeing html is because you are not writing anything back to the response. You need to do it like this:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String value = request.getParameter("value");


   response.setContentType("text/plain");  // Set content type of the response so that jQuery knows what it can expect.
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); // You want world domination, huh?
    response.getWriter().write(value);       // Write response body. (not print)
}
```

Comment: thanks , response.getWriter().write(value); helped me :D

Answer (score 0):

Give FormList servlet a different url mapping.

I guess there is confusion in resolving formlist.jsp and formlist servlet.